# Accessing method of an object within a slice throws panic

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a struct that implementing an interface in order to be accessible by the package code from outside. Though somehow the methods of the struct that was defined in the interface and defined for the struct are missing when an object contains in a slice. If object is outside the slice it works fine.

```
package RGTree

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type RGTree interface {
    GetParent () RGTree
    SetParent (RGTree)
    GetID () int
    GetParentID () int
}

type ItemTest struct {
    RGTree
    ID int
    ParentId int
}

func (it ItemTest) SetParent(item RGTree) {

}

func (it ItemTest) GetParent() RGTree {
    return it
}

func (it ItemTest) GetId() int {
    return it.ID
}

func (it ItemTest) GetParentId() int {
    return it.ParentId
}

func TestMakeTreeMap(t *testing.T) {
    var plain []RGTree

    root := ItemTest{ID: 1}

    plain = append(plain, root)
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 2, ParentId: 1})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 3, ParentId: 1})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 4, ParentId: 2})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 5, ParentId: 2})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 6, ParentId: 2})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 7, ParentId: 3})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 8, ParentId: 3})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 9, ParentId: 4})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 10, ParentId: 4})

    fmt.Println(plain[0].GetID())

    /*
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference 
        [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
        [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x4f707e]

     */

    //fmt.Println(MakeTree(root, plain))
}
```

Comment: `GetId` != `GetID`.

Comment: By the way, the reason the compiler doesn't tell you that, is because you are *embedding* the interface in the struct, which causes the interface's methods to be *promoted* to the struct, which makes the struct satisfy the interface without implementing it. And the `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` is caused by invoking the *promoted* method of the *embedded* interface which you have not initialized to anything sensible and is therefore `nil`, hence "nil pointer dereference". The lesson here is: Do not embed interfaces unless you know exactly why you're doing that.

Comment: Note that in Go interfaces are implemented/satisfied **implicitly**, you do not need to embed the interface in a type to tell the compiler that that type implements the embedded interface. All you need is to have the type implement the interface's methods, nothing more.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/qcolmMG7N_j

Comment: Sorry had a brainfart, didn't notice that the method defined with the wrong name, and ok got it thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on suggestion of mkopriva :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type RGTree interface {
    GetParent() RGTree
    SetParent(RGTree)
    GetID() int
    GetParentID() int
}

type ItemTest struct {
    ID       int
    ParentId int
}

func (it ItemTest) SetParent(item RGTree) {

}

func (it ItemTest) GetParent() RGTree {
    return it
}

func (it ItemTest) GetID() int {
    return it.ID
}

func (it ItemTest) GetParentID() int {
    return it.ParentId
}

func main() {
    var plain []RGTree

    root := ItemTest{ID: 1}

    plain = append(plain, root)
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 2, ParentId: 1})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 3, ParentId: 1})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 4, ParentId: 2})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 5, ParentId: 2})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 6, ParentId: 2})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 7, ParentId: 3})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 8, ParentId: 3})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 9, ParentId: 4})
    plain = append(plain, ItemTest{ID: 10, ParentId: 4})

    fmt.Println(plain[0].GetID())

    /*
       panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
       [recovered]
       panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
       [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x4f707e]

    */

    //fmt.Println(MakeTree(root, plain))
}
```

Output:

```
1
```